# How to correct wrong tick label position in reversed Basemap figure

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a celestial region with the Basemap. When I reverse the x axis (RA), the tick labels appear at the wrong sides. How to fixed it ？

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap    
import pylab as pl
width = 250000
m = Basemap(width=width, height=width, projection='aeqd',
            lat_0=57.1, lon_0=35.2)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(32,37.8,1),labels=[True]*5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(56,58,0.5),labels=[True]*5)

pl.gca().invert_xaxis()
pl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw parallels' labels properly, these lines of code are needed in place of the related one:

```
m.drawparallels(np.arange(56,58,0.5), ha= 'right', labels=[0, 1, 0, 0]) # for labels on left side
m.drawparallels(np.arange(56,58,0.5), ha= 'left', labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])  # for labels on right side
```

The output will be:

[image]

The complete code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap    
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

width = 250000
m = Basemap(width=width, height=width, projection='aeqd',
            lat_0=57.1, lon_0=35.2)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(32,37.8,1), labels=[0, 0, 1, 1])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(56,58,0.5), ha= 'right', labels=[0, 1, 0, 0]) # for labels on left side
m.drawparallels(np.arange(56,58,0.5), ha= 'left', labels=[1, 0, 0, 0])  # for labels on right side
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

Edit

To enable running the code with Google Colab, follow this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/swatchai/1d8d3b8bffcf03f61dc9b298278c2cb8)

Comment: Thanks for the help ! But I could not recover your figure with your commands. Could you please post your complete code ?

Comment: Thanks for the update ~ But your code does not work here.  I am using python 2.7.15,  basemap 1.2.0  matplotlib==2.2.3 . Maybe I should try with python 3.

Comment: @gerry You should do!

Comment: @gerry Please check the update in my answer. Try to run the notebook on `Colab` to see the result.